# newcommand multiple choices exam

Tags: macros, exam

I have to make several multiple choice test and to make my life easier I defined this new command

```latex
\newcommand{\preg}[6]{
\question {#1}
\begin{choices}
\choice \({#2}\)
\choice \({#3}\)
\choice \({#4}\)
\choice \({#5}\)
\choice \({#6}\)
\end{choices}}
```

But when I used it inside the `questions` it doesn't work. I used it like this

```latex
\begin{multicols}
\begin{questions}
\preg{Factoriza el siguiente polinomio:\(an+6a+n+6\),
(n+6)(a+1),
(n+1)(a-6),
(n-a)(6+1),
(n-6)(a-1),
(n-1)(a+6)}
\end{questions}
```

The errors are:

```
! Argument of \end has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.29 \end{document}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \end was complete.
<to be read again>
\par
l.29 \end{document}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
! Argument of \end has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.29 \end{document}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \end was complete.
<to be read again>
\par
l.29 \end{document}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
)
! Emergency stop.
```

I know that the error is in the command because when I don't used it, everything works fine. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There some issues with your code.

1. Every argument in `newcommand` have to be written in brackets `{...}`
2. `multicols` need an extra argument to specify how many columns you want

I add a working MWE, with some packages I believe you are using.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\preg}[6]{
\question {#1}
\begin{choices}
\choice \({#2}\)
\choice \({#3}\)
\choice \({#4}\)
\choice \({#5}\)
\choice \({#6}\)
\end{choices}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}%two columns
\begin{questions}
\preg{Factoriza el siguiente polinomio:\(an+6a+n+6\),}%
     {(n+6)(a+1),}{(n+1)(a-6),}{(n-a)(6+1),}{(n-6)(a-1),}{(n-1)(a+6)}
\end{questions}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! I didn't see those errors, I wrongly assumed that ```newcommand``` had a syntaxis of a function.

Comment: The problem with this syntax would be that LaTeX will never know when a comma is separating arguments and when is a symbol that has to be printed. ¡Es bueno saber te ha servido el código! :)